# Same line div tags

Tags: html, css

Sorry to ask such a stupid question, but it's been quite a long night and I cannot seem to get my code to display the divs on the same line.

I've searched all over Stack Overflow and none of the answers has helped. It might be a very stupid mistake I have done but I haven't noticed it.

```
<td>
  <div class='sameline'>
    <?php
      echo "<div class='hbox'>Max Health: $hp</div><div class='mbox'>Max Mana: $mana</div>";
    ?>
  </div>
</td>
.hbox {
  color:white;
  background: #dd0408; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dd0408 0%, #dd0408 0%, #bf0326 0%, #d30407 38%, #b20002 76%, #ba0003 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#dd0408), color-stop(0%,#dd0408), color-stop(0%,#bf0326), color-stop(38%,#d30407), color-stop(76%,#b20002), color-stop(100%,#ba0003)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #dd0408 0%,#dd0408 0%,#bf0326 0%,#d30407 38%,#b20002 76%,#ba0003 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #dd0408 0%,#dd0408 0%,#bf0326 0%,#d30407 38%,#b20002 76%,#ba0003 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #dd0408 0%,#dd0408 0%,#bf0326 0%,#d30407 38%,#b20002 76%,#ba0003 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #dd0408 0%,#dd0408 0%,#bf0326 0%,#d30407 38%,#b20002 76%,#ba0003 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dd0408', endColorstr='#ba0003',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  text-align:center;
  width:45%;
  height:16px;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
.mbox {
  color:white;
  background: #00a4f7; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00a4f7 1%, #00b7f9 43%, #009ec3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#00a4f7), color-stop(43%,#00b7f9), color-stop(100%,#009ec3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00a4f7 1%,#00b7f9 43%,#009ec3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00a4f7 1%,#00b7f9 43%,#009ec3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00a4f7 1%,#00b7f9 43%,#009ec3 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #00a4f7 1%,#00b7f9 43%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00a4f7', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  text-align:center;
  width:45%;
  height:16px;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
#sameline {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: @dda The majority of your corrections were unneeded and irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.hbox, .mbox {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your answer worked. I'm surprised I didn't think of that I can be so stupid. Thank you Arbel.

Comment: Note: you'll need to use `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` for this to work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` to both .mbox and .hbox.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you need the two divs inside `<div class="sameline">` to appear next to each other

so a css rule like

```
.hbox, .mbox {float:left}
```

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.sameline div {float: left;}`.

(BTW, try to avoid posting PHP when asking CSS/HTML questions, as it makes it harder to read/interpret the code‚though not too difficult here. Get the HTML from your browser's source code, if necessary.)

Also note that `sameline` is a class, so this won't work unless you change the `#` to a `.`:

```
#sameline {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I was using php aswell because I was echoing the html content within the php data. Sorry if this confused you or any others.

Answer (score 0):

if you add `float: left;` to `.mbox` and `.hbox` it should work.
Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PMeX6/).