# html css make div be on the same line as text

Tags: css, html

My question is, how do I avoid having the text on a new row?

My code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p >Seating availability.</p>
<p ><div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: green; border: 0px;" ></div> There are available seats.</p>
<p ><div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: yellow; border: 0px;" ></div> Available seats are decreasing.</p>
<p ><div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: orange; border: 0px;" ></div> Less than 15% of seats available.</p>
<p ><div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: red; border: 0px;" ></div> There are no available seats.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How should I code this?

Comment: Search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[html]+div+same+line+is%3Aq; Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/12171992/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16312650/1741542, ...

Comment: problem is your <p> tag.this tag take each line as separate paragraph.so use single <p> for all the div.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add display: inline-block to div

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   div
   {
     display: inline-block;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p >Seating availability.</p>
<p><div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: green; border: 0px;" ></div>There are available seats.</p>
<p ><div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: yellow; border: 0px;" ></div> Available seats are decreasing.</p>
<p ><div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: orange; border: 0px;" ></div> Less than 15% of seats available.</p>
<p ><div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: red; border: 0px;" ></div> There are no available seats.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are so many [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) properties are available:

Try using `display:inline-block;`

```
div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: green; border: 0px;display:inline-block;" ></div>
```

Hope this helps!

[**fiddle-Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jnbuC/)

Remove `<p></p>` tag just use `<div>` as `<p>` is always takes new line.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jnbuC/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use span instead of div and add (display:inline-block;)
paragraph (p) Can't Contain (div) but can contain (span)
'

   Seating availability.

There are available seats.
        Available seats are decreasing.
       
       Less than 15% of seats available.      
           There are no available seats.
   
'

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your css file

```
div {
    margin: 5px 10px 0 0 ;
    float:left;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WRV9F/)